# Separate page for comments using permalinks and add_rewrite_rule

Tags: comments, url-rewriting

I have been at this for days now, going through plenty of answers here, guides on using .htaccess, guides on using add_rewrite_rule() within Wordpress and examples throughout the web. I am not sure if there is a malfunction in my regex to detect the correct URL, or a disconnect between what I want to accomplish and what can be accomplished.

Basically, I am trying to separate comments from posts (or better yet, comments from content) by forcing them to a separate page "associated" with the content. So for example, `http://localhost/wp/2011/02/25/hello-world-2/` is a post, and the comments for that post should appear at `http://localhost/wp/2011/02/25/hello-world-2/comments/`. Now, a ["little bird"](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/separate-comments-from-specified-posts#post-205938) once said that this could be done with the following:

`RewriteRule ^archives/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([^/]+)/comments/?$ /index.php?year=$1&monthnum=$2&day=$3&name=$4&comments=1 [QSA,L]` (seeing as I do not really need to work inside the /archives/ for my above example to work, I removed it), which I translated into this plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Gingah Permalink Rewrite
Plugin URI: http://gingahmail.com/wordpress/
Description: Useful Permalink-structures, that required a plugin to work.
Version: 1.0
Author: Gingah
Author URI: http://gingahmail.com/
*/

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'gingah_rewrite_activate' );
function gingah_rewrite_activate() {
    gingah_rewrite();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'gingah_rewrite_deactivate' );
function gingah_rewrite_deactivate() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('admin_init', 'gingah_rewrite');
function gingah_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([^/]+)/comments/?$', '/index.php?year=$1&monthnum=$2&day=$3&name=$4&comments=1 [QSA,L]', 'top' );
}
?>
```

(based on countless examples *just* like it, around the web)

This does, however, not work. Even though, visiting `http://localhost/wp/2011/02/25/hello-world-2/?comments=1` does produce the expected result. So what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress rewrite rules by default are no longer stored in the Apache configuration, but are handled by WordPress itself. This was probably not the case when that forum topic was written (5 years ago), but currently only "external" rules end up in the Apache configuration, all others are stored in the database and handled by [the `WP::parse_request()` function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L110).

This means you should leave off the Apache-specific parts in your `add_rewrite_rule()` call. The following code looks better:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    // The beginning `^` is added by WordPress
    '([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([^/]+)/comments/?$',
    // `$1` should be replaced with `$matches[1]`
    'index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&name=$matches[4]&comments=1',
    'top'
);
```

When I tested this with [my Rewrite analyzer plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/a-tool-to-analyze-rewrite-rules/3608#3608), I noticed that `comments` is not a standard query variable, so remember that you will have to handle that too.

Comment: At the very least, this now shows the post itself. I tried adding the suggested at `http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3537/need-help-with-friendly-urls-in-wordpress/3575#3575` (substituting _designer_name_ with _comments_ to fix the query variable as you suggest, but `http://localhost/wp/2011/02/25/hello-world-2/comments/` still shows just the post.

Comment: @Gingah: But if you can set this extra query variable, then you can also hook into `template_include` to select a specific theme file that will only show the comments and not the posts.

Comment: I guess that would work, but will that still allow `http://localhost/wp/2011/02/25/hello-world-2/comments/` to show the comments?

Comment: @Gingah: Yes, you can think of it as two different theme files, based on the same `single.php`: one that shows the post but no comments, and one that shows the comments but no post. You could even do this in one `single.php` if you read the query variable there.

Comment: I added the functionality to the `single.php`-file. So, when a post is view, comments are hidden, but if a GET variable called comments is passed to the page (and is equal to 1), only comments are shown. Is this the right way? I still cannot get `/comments/` to only show comments (using `if (isset($_GET['comments']) && $_GET['comments'] == 1)` to check if the _comments_-variable is set).

Comment: @Gingah: If you want to do this via the `/comments/` part of the URL, you should add `comments` to the list of public query vars (with the `query_vars` filter), and then you can use `get_query_var('comments')` to check for its presence.

Comment: That was indeed the missing piece! Thank you very much.