# Access or edit custom generated permalinks with WP_Rewrite

Tags: permalinks, filters, templates, url-rewriting

I want to create custom permalinks for my plugin using `WP_Rewrite`. I found the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Rewrite) the have great examples and [this stack topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/need-help-with-add-rewrite-rule) also explained a lot to me.

Currently I've got the following code based on the codex and update 3 from the stack overflow question:

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'custom_permalinks' );
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_query_vars' );
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'custom_flush_rules' );

function custom_flush_rules() {
    $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );
    if( !isset($rules['(employees)/([^/]*)$']) ) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
}

function custom_permalinks( $rules ) {
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['(employees)/([^/]*)$'] = 'index.php?pagename=employees&employees_slug=$matches[1]';

    return $newrules + $rules;
}

function custom_query_vars( $vars ) {
    array_push($vars, 'employees_slug');
    return $vars;
}
```

When I visit `/employees/name_of_the_employee/` the same page is represented as when visiting `/employees`, so there isn't shown an 404 page (which means the new rewrite rules are applied). But when I `print_r($_GET)` an empty array is printed. I also can't figure out how to set another template for the `/name_of_the_employee` page instead of the parent page.

In [this stack topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3537/need-help-with-friendly-urls-in-wordpress) there is a reference to `get_query_var('employees_slug')` but instead of printing the employee name, the parent page slug `/employees` is shown..

Anyone can tell me how to access the new children pages using a template or how I can see while it is showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query vars don't end up in `$_GET`, use [`get_query_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) to fetch or check the value of your custom query vars set by rewrite rules.

Your rule is currently returning `employees` as `employees_slug` because your rule has two capture groups, so `employees_slug` is held in `$matches[2]`, not `$matches[1]`. The first capture group is unnecessary though, so the parens can be removed.

To apply a template, you can filter [`page_template`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/page_template) and check for the presence of your query var.

```
function wpd_employees_page_template( $template ){
    if( get_query_var( 'employees_slug' ) ){
        $template = locate_template( 'employees.php' );
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'page_template', 'wpd_employees_page_template' );
```

Also note that a slightly simpler way to add a rule is via [`add_rewrite_rule`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) hooked to the `init` action rather than filtering `rewrite_rules_array`.

Comment: Awesome! Everything is working now.