# How do I apply friendly URL permalinks to a custom WordPress template?

Tags: htaccess, posts, permalinks

I have a WordPress site. I created a custom template page which is referenced like follows:

```
/archive-template.php?posttype=publications&taxo=countries&slug=kenya
```

How can I have these links using permalink? .htaccess? plugin? This is so the link above would look like this:

```
/archives/publications/countries/kenya
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code

In your main hooks file (maybe in **functions.php**)

```
add_action('init', 'my_custom_rewrite_rules');
```

Then add this function

```
function my_custom_rewrite_rules() {

    // The rule
    // Input: archives/publications/countries/kenya
    // Output: archive-template.php?posttype=publications&taxo=countries&slug=kenya
    add_rewrite_rule('archives/publications/countries/([^/]+)/', 'archive-template.php?posttype=publications&taxo=countries&slug=$matches[1]', 'top');

    // Flush the rules (to activate them)
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

To learn more about regex and rewrite rules, those links might help

- https://regexone.com/
- http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/need-help-with-add-rewrite-rule
- http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3537/need-help-with-friendly-urls-in-wordpress
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cd-jy85LQtU

And to test your rewrite rules, you can use any plugin you like, but I love this one: [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/)

**NOTE** Sorry  I did not write the rule for you, I really have something that came up and do not have time to write the rule and test it, however, I hope the resources that I provided would help you. Good luck.

**NOTE 2** Updated the rule. It is not tested. But this should give you a good start.

Comment: Thanks Greeso! It's actually the rule what I'm struggling with. If you have some time, maybe you can throw some light here? Thanks again.

Comment: Updated the answer, not tested.